External network connection settings
After installing Ubuntu Server 22.04 in virtualbox and setting the network adapter mode to bridged adapter, I have an issue with IP not being assigned dynamically. Of course, even if you set a static IP, you cannot connect to an external network.
It can't be done.

Check network interface: ip a  ==> no inet settings

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf file as follows: Add nameserver:   ==> No network connection


nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Check firewall settings
After enabling UFW, set default rules   ==> No network connection
Allows SSH and HTTP/HTTPS connections

